# Popup add custom style

Tags: html, jquery

I'm trying to add max-width to popover, but can't seem to get it working. I have multiple popover on the page but only want to add max to the one with pop1 id.

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function(i) {
  var pop = {};
  pop.container = 'body';
  $(this).popover(pop);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="content"><span data-trigger="hover click" data-toggle="popover" id="pop1" data-content="this is a popup" title="popup">Pop1</span></div>

<div class="content"><span id="pop2" data-trigger="hover click" data-toggle="popover" data-content="this is a popup" title="popup">Pop2</span></div>
```

Comment: Next time please take more time to make a [mcve] - it helps us answer. I made you a working snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want the answer in CSS, but here it is:

```
.pop1 {
max-width: XYZpx;
}
```

`XYZ` is the max width you want it to be (ex: 500). You can also change `px` (pixels) to a different unit, such as `vw` (view width) or `%` (percentage) as an example. `pop1` can also be changed to the class of the thing you're trying to give a max width to, in your case, `popover` I believe.

Comment: Did you try? Why would the popover change size because of the span, which cannot change width unless you make it display:block

Comment: Oops, forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

This SHOULD have worked - why not I do not get.

Anyway posted for reference

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function(i) {
  var pop = {};
  const $my = $(this).closest('#my');
  console.log($my.attr("id"))
  pop.container = $my ? "#my" : "body";
  $(this).popover(pop);
});
```

```css
body > .popover {
  width: 300px !important;
}
#my > .popover {
  width: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>


<div class="content"><span data-trigger="hover click" data-toggle="popover" data-content="this is a popup" title="popup">Pop2</span></div>

<div id="my">
  <div class="content"><span data-trigger="hover click" data-toggle="popover" data-content="this is a popup" title="popup">Pop</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```